# How to change laser scan point size and colour in ros3djs?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros3djs, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm visualising laser scan points in `ros3dlib` using the code snippet below. This works well but the points seem to be displayed as big white blocks on my web GUI. How do I change these to small red points?

```
let frontLaserScan = new ROS3D.LaserScan({
    ros : this.ros,
    tfClient : tfClient,
    topic : '/lidar_scan',
    rootObject : viewer.scene,
});
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375971/how-to-change-laser-scan-point-size-and-colour-in-ros3djs?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Worked it out! Just need to set the `material` option like this:

```
let frontLaserScan = new ROS3D.LaserScan({
    ros : this.ros,
    tfClient : tfClient,
    topic : '/lidar_scan',
    rootObject : viewer.scene,
    material : { size: 0.1, color: 0xff0000 }
});
```

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0